# How to design DDR3 PCB without any termination resistor in processor and RAM connection

Tags: pcb-design, high-frequency, high-speed, termination, ddr3

As I'm going to design my first high-speed PCB, I'm confused with some mismatches between what i see in high-speed PCB design tutorials and what i see in real world designs. in the PCB handbook named "RIGHT THE FIRST TIME" by "LEE W. RITCHEY", it's discussed that the transmission lines higher than 1/4 TEL will fail from reflection. In some boards like raspberry pi 3 and banana pi BPI-M64, i don't see any termination resistor between Processor and RAM IC(s). As the frequency of the Allwinner A64 and 4 512 DDR3 RAMS in BPI-M64 is about 800MHz i think 1/4 TEL is less than 1 Centimeter but in the board I see the routes are longer than 2 on 3 Cm without any termination. the The question is:

Is it realy possible to do such designs without termination resistors or I am calculating in a wrong way?

Comment: Careful, the _Transmission Electrical Length_ has nothing(!) to do with your clock rate. It has to do with the highest significant frequency component in your rising edge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DDR3 has integrated (on-die) termination for the data lines, and Vtt termination for other lines. Therefore, not all lines require external termination resistors. You will find that several high-speed IO standards have integrated termination, as this avoid the parasitics, extra space, and extra routing of "regular" discrete termination.

I suggest you read [this Altera DDR3 termination & layout guidelines document](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/ja_JP/pdfs/literature/an/an520.pdf) as well as [this Wikipedia article: On-die termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-die_termination) and [this presentation on DDR3/DDR3L/DDR4](https://web.archive.org/web/20150616052825/http://www.keysight.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/5Micron.pdf??&cc=US&lc=eng).

DDR3 termination is a very complicated subject, as different bits of the interface have different termination situations, as well as on-die termination which can also be dynamic (register settings can modify the value of the on-die termination). To better understand the nuances, you'll likely want to look at several DDR3 controller/DRAM datasheets and reference designs.

Finally, see [TIDEP0012](http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDEP0012#technicaldocuments) for an example of a DDR3 reference design that does not use Vtt termination.

To sum up, DDR3 is somewhat of a special case when it comes to "conventional" high-speed digital designs, due to integrated features that make it easier to use. Ritchey's book is a good one, I would also suggest reading Howard Johnson's and Henry Ott's texts for more high-speed digital design considerations. Also, without looking at the schematics, it's difficult to fully understand the circuit at hand. Last I checked, the Raspi 3 was still closed hardware. Have you got a schematic? You'll have a far better time designing circuits by reading the datasheet and looking at reference designs than by trying to infer designs from closed hardware.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer. That's all I need to know at this time.

Comment: Also see [LS1012ARDB](https://www.nxp.com/design/qoriq-developer-resources/qoriq-ls1012a-development-board:LS1012A-RDB) for an example of a DDR3L reference design without any "off-die" termination.

Comment: Fun fact: Dr Howard Johnson was a student of Lee Ritchey.